# Radio Buttons in dojo framework

Tags: html, dojo, dijit.layout

I have created a div, something similar to below. Which should create 2 radio button, each button having its independent value.

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="colors" value="green"
        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton"> Green
    <input type="radio" name="colors" value="red"
          data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton"> Red
</div>
```

I need to create a controller, which on click, should call a function where i can write my relevant code.

I am new to Dojo framework. Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: you mean you want to create this last in programmatic way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the html declare:

```html
<input id="red_radio" />
<input id="green_radio" />
```

Then you could create a function like:

```js
require([
    "dojo/parser",
    "dijit/form/RadioButton",
    "dijit/form/Button", // used for example purpose
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(parser, RadioButton){
createRadios(domid, name, check, val) {
                var radioOne = new RadioButton({
                    checked: check,
                    value: val,
                    name: name,
                    onChange: (a) => {
                        if (dijit.byId(domid).checked && dijit.byId(domid).value == 'red') {
                            //code when red
                        }
                        else if (dijit.byId(domid).checked && dijit.byId(domid).value == 'green') {
                            //code when green
                        }
                    }
                }, domid);
                radioOne.startup();
            },

createRadios("red_radio", "colors", true, "red");
createRadios("green_radio", "colors", false, "green");
});
```

call the function to create each radio,
I hope this would help you,
also you could see the documentation : https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/RadioButton.html